# Validate for more than one format with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a phone number field that is set up to validate using preg_match:

```
function ValidPhone($phone) {
    return preg_match('/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/', trim($phone));
}
```

This ensures that phone numbers are entered in the xxx-xxx-xxxx format and that it's numeric.

I'm not very familiar with regexp; can anyone tell me how I'd expand this to allow more than one format? i.e. xxx xxx xxxx or xxx.xxx.xxxx or (xxx) xxx-xxxx

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using a regex to match, you need to know exactly what formats you need to support. I think a better option would be what Sean suggested below. A regex to match more than one or two formats would get pretty complex.

Comment: Unfortunately we do need to match exact formats, the ones I mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to just strip out everything that isn't numeric first:

```
function ValidatePhone($phone) {
    $phone = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $phone);
    return strlen($phone) == 10;
}
```

Since you are validating the format, and not the content, this should do it:

```
function ValidatePhone($phone) {
    $patterns = array(
        '\d{3}([-\. ])\d{3}\g{-1}\d{4}',
        '\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}'
        );

    $phone = trim($phone);

    foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
        if (preg_match('/^' . $pattern . '$/', $phone))
            return true;
    }

    return false;                                                                                                                   
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't what we need. We need to validate for very specific formats, i.e. the ones I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Updated.  As an aside, if this is for validating user-supplied data in a UI, do your users a favor and be more forgiving about what you will accept.  Ideally you would only store the 10 digits of the phone number (assuming NPA numbering) and format it however you want on the way back out to the UI.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try and see. It's partially for user-supplied data, but the same script is used to validate data that we receive from an external service, so the validation has to be done when we receive the data, not when it's entered.

Answer (score 0):

For US numbers:

```
\(?[2-9]\d\d)?[ -\.]?[2-9]\d\d[ -\.]?\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{3} \d{3} \w{4})|(\d{3}-\d{3}\-\d{4})|(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4})
```

`\d:` one digit number [0-9]

`\d{3}:` three one digit number

`|:` logical OR